# Logistic Regression Using Mahout

Tags: mahout, logistic-regression

I've just read [this](http://technobium.com/logistic-regression-using-apache-mahout/On) interesting article about logistic regression using Mahout. The tutorial is clear to me... but how would a real use case looks like? For instance, when a [web] application first starts, some training data needs to be processed... and the result is kept in an `OnlineLogisticRegression` instance. Then, to test new data, one just needs to invoke `OnlineLogisticRegression.classifyFull` and look at the probability — represented by a value between 0 and 1 — that the data falls in a given classification.

But what if I want to improve a model and train it with additional data while the [web] application is online? The idea would be to train the model with additional data once a week or similar in order to improve accuracy. What's the correct way to implement such a mechanism? Are there significant performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know whats your usecase but I have implemented like below.
I used Naivebayes. current flow using my model which is online.
Now after 15 days I used to add new training data into previous training data and generate a new model. once the new model is created its been replaced with the online model by cron.